# Duplicate Error on Upsert

Tags: upsert, externalid, jitterbit

I have created an operation in Jitterbit to run an upsert on two custom objects and one standard object: Lead, Project_c and ProjectLead_c

The ProjectLead object is just a junction object that relates the other two. Everything runs properly, data upserts and objects are related but in my log files there are a handful of external ID's that receive a duplicate error. When I query for those external ID's they are not found. There are other ID's that also get the duplicate error but those ID's are found in salesforce.

Does anyone know why this could be happening ? I have disabled duplicate rules already but no luck

Answer (score 0):

External ID fields are often created with 'Unique ID' field setting. You can check the field definition details page of the external ID field (`General Options` section). This will prevent duplicate record insertion with the same external ID. Assuming that the 'Unique ID' field setting is turned ON in your case, the following might happen:

> When I query for those external ID's they are not found.

It's possible that 2 records with same external ID are getting getting upserted in the same transaction or batch.

> There are other ID's that also get the duplicate error but those ID's
> are found in salesforce.

Possibly because there is a single record with the external ID already and when you try to upsert another record with the external ID, it's seen as duplicate.